# Locking grid in pure CSS

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I am on the hunt for a pure CSS alternative to [ExtJS Locking Grid](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/examples/kitchensink/?classic#locking-grid) which, I suspect, might be possible with [CSS Grid Layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Specifically, the requirement is that you can both scroll the grid vertically having the first row stay still, and horizontally — having the first column stay still.

Is this possible without JavaScript?

Comment: You cant detect scroll direction in css. So the answer is no, not without js.

Comment: You can make the content overflow for a cell in the grid be scroll. Then its height will be that of the rows it takes up, and the page won't scroll, the cell will. You could put more content into that one cell if you really wanted to

Comment: What have you tried and what is your HTML structure ? (obviously a table but , provide your code in order to be helped)

Comment: @G-Cyr No code tried so far as the thing might not be even possible. CSS gurus should be able to tell that. And a table does not seem so obvious to me here.

Comment: I supposed a table so content is accessible to screen readers and search engines and stay readable at screen when CSS used is not supported by the visitor's browser. For the guru's part, it requires anyway some tags to apply style to ;) .